# How to show badge count on app icon Xamarin Forms (Android)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I need to show a badge count on the app icon in Xamarin.Forms (Android). I'm using the Plugin.Badge package to show badge in TabbedPageView, but now I need to put badge count on the app icon, like this image below:

[image: Badge count on the app icon android]

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: Android does not have support for this. Certain launcher implementations offer this for their home screens.

Comment: So how many apps have this notification on Android, for example, the Facebook app and Whatsapp?

Comment: They only offer those badges on devices with a launcher that supports it, and they have code that supports the different APIs for those launchers.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question .  This a very unique question that is not answered.  All questions listed above are not specific to Xamarin.

Comment: You can! From the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges